# getLastLocation() return null after moving code

Tags: java, android

**PROBLEM**

I can't understand why now `getLastLocation()` returns null. I've just moved the  snippet to get the last known location under the check permission snippet and now everytime I run the app 'location' is null (before worked).
Could you help me to find the issue? Thanks

**MapsActivity.java**

```
    ...
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            // Get fused location client
            mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
            // Create a Toolbar
            Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);


            // Set the toolbar
            myToolbar.setTitle("RSSI Map");
            myToolbar.setSubtitle("A Connectivity Map Builder");
            setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        }

        @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

                    mMap = googleMap;


                    // Check if localization permission is granted
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
                        }
                    }

                    // Get last location
                    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                                    if (location != null) {
                                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                        latitude = location.getLatitude();

                                    }
                                }
                            });
    ...
```

**SOLUTION**

This works but really I don't know exactly why. 
I removed the code to get last known location through fuse provider client from `OnMapReady` callback and I moved it inside `checkLocationSettings` method. 
I needed also to get location update so I followed this tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates .
I use `createLocationRequest` method to create a request and `checkLocationSettings` to see if the settings are appropriated. If they are appropriated I call `getLastKnownLocation` (the snippet of code that I removed from `OnMapReady`) inside `checkLocationSettings`.

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


            mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
            Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);

            // Create location request and location callback
            createLocationRequest();
            createLocationCallback();

            // Set the toolbar
            myToolbar.setTitle("RSSI Map");
            myToolbar.setSubtitle("A Connectivity Map Builder");
            setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);



            // If location permission is granted initialize Map and check location settings
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                mapSync();

                // Check if location settings are appropriate for location request and if is the case invoke getLastLocation()
                checkLocationSettings();

            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
                }
            }
        }

 @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

            mMap = googleMap;

            // Check if localization permission is granted
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
                }
            }




 public void checkLocationSettings() {
            // Get and check location services settings
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

            SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(MapsActivity.this);
            Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

            task.addOnSuccessListener(MapsActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
                    // location requests here
                    getLastKnownLocation();

                }
            });
...
}
```

Comment: add permission in onCreate method insted of onMapReady

Comment: I think your check for request permission is useless ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ), please check if you have enabled the location permission in settings -> apps and also check if location is enabled. Also check your manifest for location permission. Check if in your onRequestPermissionsResult after permission have been granted locaiton is still null

Comment: @WaleedAsim  I can't because in the permission I use mMap which is declare in onMapReady callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow should be:

1. Add location permission in AndroidManifest.xml
2. Check if user has given that permission, if yes, check location settings; and of not then first ask for permission
3. If permission is granted and location settings are ON, then you should do what you want.

In your case, from the code you've shown, you are not checking location settings and just after requesting permission, you are trying to `getLastLocation()` which should be inside of `if` statement when permission is granted and when permission is granted in `onRequestPermissionsResult()`

**EDIT:**
Add/Change the following code:

1.

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
        if (mLocationRequest == null) {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        }
    }
```

2.

```
private void checkLocationSettings() {

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

        final Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result =
                LocationServices.getSettingsClient(MapsActivity.this).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {

                Log.e(TAG, "onComplete() called with: task = [" + task.isComplete() + "]");
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
                // location requests here.
                // ...
                getLastKnownLocation(mFusedLocationClient);
            }
        });


        result.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure() called with: e = [" + e + "]");
                if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                    // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                    // by showing the user a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                        resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MapsActivity.this,
                                REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("MapsActivity", "onActivityResult() called with: requestCode = [" + requestCode + "], resultCode = [" + resultCode + "], data = [" + data + "]");
        getLastKnownLocation(mFusedLocationClient);
    }


    public void getLastKnownLocation(FusedLocationProviderClient cl) {
        // Get last location
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess() called with: location = [" + location + "]");
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                        if (location != null) {
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            Log.e("MapsActivity", "onSuccess() called with: location = [" + location + "]");
                            LatLng mCurrentLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mCurrentLocation).title("Current position"));
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mCurrentLocation));

                            // Set zoom level
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(19.0f));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "value is " + latitude + "poi" + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    createLocationRequest();
                    checkLocationSettings();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This app requires location permission to be granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
                break;


        }
```

3. And only this code related to location in `onMapReady()`:

   ```
   // Check if localization permission is granted
   if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
           == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
           && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
           == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
       createLocationRequest();
       checkLocationSettings();


   } else {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this
                   , new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}
                   , MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
       }
   }
   ```

Make sure you have both below permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: I've tried as you said.
I've created a function getLastKnownLocation which call getLastLocation on mFusedLocationClient . Then I called it inside onRequestPermission (if permission are granted) and in the other permission check (also if permission are granted, but also this doesn't work. I'm getting crazy.

Comment: Please post your whole file code. I will communicate changes if any

Comment: where is better to post it? Should I edit the question or send you a link?

Comment: Edit the question and paste link of file in it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SqhSkpzB . Anyway although on pastebin getLastKnownLocation declaration misses the argument, I added it.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follow:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Get fused location client
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    // Create a Toolbar
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);


    // Set the toolbar
    myToolbar.setTitle("RSSI Map");
    myToolbar.setSubtitle("A Connectivity Map Builder");
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);


    /**
    * Request permission here
    */
    reqPerms();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            /**
            * Load the map after all perms are granted
            */
            loadMapAsync();
        } else {
            /**
            * Notify user that the app needs some permissions to do some tasks!
            */
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Get last location
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if (location != null) {
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }
        }
    );
}

private void reqPerms() {
    // Check if localization permission is granted
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        /**
        * Load the map after all perms are granted
        */
        loadMapAsync();
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
        }    
    }
}

private void loadMapAsync() {
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

EDIT:
Please, in your manifest, try to add `MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION` too and request permission for it in the Activity.

Comment: Niente da fare, grazie lo stesso

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
requestPermissions()
```

This method functions asynchronously -
[docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java)
. You need to call:

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                            .addOnSuccessListener()
```

after permission are granted.

2) check if  `locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)`

3) add to `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()`

```
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                    if (task.getResult() == null) {
                        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(), mLocationCallback, null);
                    }
                }
            })

.addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCanceled() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCanceled: mFusedLocationClient addOnCanceledListener");
                    }
                });
```

PS if you check it on Samsung s8 or s9 it will be problem, and i don't know why...